# Can I extend the command class so that the button that binds to it is automatically disabled?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

In my application I bound my buttons to commands with "MVVM".
My command is implemented as follows:

```
        public Command CommandLoadStuff
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async () =>
                {
                    await DoLongStuff();
                });
            }
        }
```

The problem is that these commands are async and the user can click them multiple times causing the code to execute multiple times also.

As a first approach i used CanExecute:

```
        public Command CommandLoadStuff
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async () =>
                {
                    AppIsBusy = true;
                    await DoLongStuff();
                    AppIsBusy = false;
                },() => !AppIsBusy);
            }
        }
```

Now I wonder if there isn't a better way than to handle the CanExecute for each command individually.

Since I initialize the command every time with "new" I wonder if the class "Command" could not be extended accordingly. It should block a second click of the button during the lifespan with CanExecute (Posibly in the Constructor?) and release it after the execution of the command is finished. ( Possibly in the Dispose function?)

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending the class command this way is not possible, as far as I can tell, because `Execute` is non-virtual and you have to pass the `execute` action to the constructor. Anyway, there is still a way. `Command` derives from `ICommand` which has the following interface

```cs
public interface ICommand
{
    event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    void Execute(object data);

    bool CanExecute(object data);
}
```

You could create a class `AsyncBlockingCommand` (or whatsoever) that will return will return the respective value from `CanExecute` depending on whether an async method is still running (I know that there are issues with `async void` methods, so handle with care)

```cs
public class AsyncBlockingCommand : ICommand
{
    bool _canExecute = true;
    Func<Task> _toExecute;

    public AsyncBlockingCommand(Func<Task> toExecute)
    {
        _toExecute = toExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public async void Execute(object data)
    {
        _canExecute = false;
        RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        await _toExecute();
        _canExecute = true;
        RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object data) => _canExecute; 

    private void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Before your async method is executed, `_canExecute` is set to `false` and `CanExecuteChanged` is raised. This way, your `Button` will get notified of `CanExecute` having changed and disable itself. Vice versa after the async method has been called. (Probably the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` will have to be invoked on the main thread.)

Comment: Thank you very much! This is similar to the experiment i did but i forgot to await the execution and so my command got enabled again instantly! Your snipped will solve my problem. Thanks! :)

-> I edited your post because the invoke function requires 2 Parameters. CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IsEnabled` property to make the `Button` cannot be clicked.
Like following code.

```
<Button 
    Text="click"
    Command={Binding Button1Command}
    IsEnabled={Binding AreButtonsEnabled} />
```

If the value of `IsEnabled` is false, you can see this button, it is grey, if you click it, it will not execute any command.

[image]

Here is MyViewModel code.

```
private bool _areButtonsEnabled = true;

public bool AreButtonsEnabled
{
    get => _areButtonsEnabled;
    set
    {
        if (_areButtonsEnabled != value)
        {
            _areButtonsEnabled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AreButtonsEnabled)); // assuming your view model implements INotifyPropertyChanged
        }
    }
}

public ICommand Button1Command { get; protected set; }

public MyViewModel()
{
    Button1Command = new Command(HandleButton1Tapped);
}

private void HandleButton1Tapped()
{
    // Run on the main thread, to make sure that it is getting/setting the proper value for AreButtonsEnabled
    // And note that calls to Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread are queued, therefore
    // you can be assured that AreButtonsEnabled will be set to false by one button's command
    // before the value of AreButtonsEnabled is checked by another button's command.
    // (Assuming you don't change the value of AreButtonsEnabled on another thread)
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async() => 
    {
        if (AreButtonsEnabled)
        {
            AreButtonsEnabled = false;
            // DoLongStuff code
            await  Task.Delay(2000);
            AreButtonsEnabled = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Some thoughts: `BebinInvokeOnMainThread` is called from a method that should already be on the main thread. Hence, I'd think that it's not necessary where you put it. Furthermore you'd like to avoid doing long-running calculations on the main thread.